# error when using pip on virtualenv

Tags: python, ssl, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to start an environment using virtualenv but i can't install the packages i need because pip wont download them.

According to what I've found the problem was that the version of pip i was using didn't work well because of SSL veryfying reasons so I downgraded to pip 1.2.1 and pip would then download the packages with no problems.

However whenever I try to use virtualenv it automatically installs the newest version of pip which gives me the SSL veryfying errors.

Is there any way to make virtualenv install an older version of pip?

I'm fairly new to python and it's the first time ive used virtualenv.
Also I'm using the terminal on OSX Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See virtualenv documentation -

https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html

Under "The --extra-search-dir option"

Haven't tried it but in the docs it says:

> "This option allows you to provide your own versions of setuptools
>   and/or pip to use instead of the embedded versions that come with
>   virtualenv."

Comment: The option worked but the documentation doesn't do a very good job at explaining how to use it. You have to include the --no-pip option along with the --extra-search-dir option otherwise virtualenv will ignore it and download its default pip.   Anyways THANK YOU SO MUCH!!